# Single RadioButtonFor has two ID attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radiobuttonfor

I have used RadioButtonFor() with overridden IDs in many places in my project, but in just one place I have very odd behaviour.  The rendered input control has two ID attributes, one with a lower case "id" whose value is that of the assigned property, and one with "Id" whose value is that of my assigned ID value....

```
<%: Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(model) model.HasAccount, False, New With {.id = "HasAccount_No"})%>
```

..this is rendering as...

```
<input Id="HasAccount_No" id="HasAccount" name="HasAccount" type="radio" value="False" />
```

Any thoughts as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you're specifyinh the id-attribute in all lower case in your HTML-helper. This normally only happens if your casing is different.

Comment: Yep, I thought of that, but the code above is copy & pasted from my project!

Comment: I've even tried retyping the line and deleting the original one, but renders just the same.  There's no javascript which might be adding the ID either!